# How to fetch any click on any Object within a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using Datatables and i have a calendar with a toolbar, this has some buttons like previous day, next day, today etc.

All those buttons of this toolbar are wrapped in a div. My intension is to reload my datatable when the user clicks on any element within this div.

The click event does not really working so far what I have, see below my code.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL5w6xos/)

```js
$(".fc-toolbar").on('click', function(updateCalendarGroupList) {
  $('#CalendarTable').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fc-toolbar fc-header-toolbar"> <!-- want to fetch all click events on all elements within this div -->
  <div class="fc-left">
    <button type="button" class="fc-today-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">today</button>
    <div class="fc-button-group">
      <button type="button" class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow">Previous</span></button>
      <button type="button" class="fc-next-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-right-single-arrow">Forward</span>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-right">
    <div class="fc-button-group">
      <button type="button" class="fc-timelineDay-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-state-active">Day</button><button type="button" class="fc-timelineThreeDays-button fc-button fc-state-default">3 days</button>
      <button type="button" class="fc-agendaWeek-button fc-button fc-state-default">week</button>
      <button type="button" class="fc-month-button fc-button fc-state-default">month</button>
      <button type="button" class="fc-listDay-button fc-button fc-state-default">Agenda day</button>
      <button type="button" class="fc-listWeek-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right">Agenda week</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-center">
    <h2>July 2, 2017</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your table?

Comment: The table is not relevant. The click event doesn't trigger.

Comment: but it triggers See demo : https://jsfiddle.net/mgfzhbt4/2/

Comment: Ok, i got the problem. It wasn't a `$(document).ready(function() {});` thus wouldn't fire after all elements were loaded. Sorry :D